# Not enough free disk space on disk '/boot' but I don't have old kenels

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk-usage

Not enough free disk space on disk '/boot' but I don't have old kenels, here is how my boot partition looks like...

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   224297 may  6 10:33 config-5.0.0-15-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 may 19 18:29 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66604370 jun  2 09:09 initrd.img-5.0.0-15-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 feb  8  2015 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 ene 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 ene 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 ene 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  4377272 may  6 10:33 System.map-5.0.0-15-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8703736 may  6 12:11 vmlinuz-5.0.0-15-generic
```

Furthermore I do see a generous amount of free space at the boot partition...

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        1.5G  1.9M  1.5G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  103G   46G   52G  47% /
tmpfs                        7.5G  136M  7.3G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2                   3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/91
/dev/loop0                    35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop1                   1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop4                   8.5M  8.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/77
/dev/loop5                   313M  313M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/48
/dev/loop3                   301M  301M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/45
/dev/loop6                    15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop8                   152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/55
/dev/loop7                   519M  519M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/123
/dev/loop10                   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop11                   15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/288
/dev/loop9                   519M  519M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/124
/dev/loop12                   81M   81M     0 100% /snap/audacity/356
/dev/loop13                   89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop16                  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/86
/dev/loop14                  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/88
/dev/loop15                   93M   93M     0 100% /snap/openscad-nightly/1035
/dev/loop17                  1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop19                  310M  310M     0 100% /snap/datagrip/47
/dev/loop18                   15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/284
/dev/loop21                   81M   81M     0 100% /snap/audacity/342
/dev/loop22                   54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop23                   36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop24                   93M   93M     0 100% /snap/openscad-nightly/1009
/dev/loop25                  175M  175M     0 100% /snap/inkscape/4693
/dev/loop20                  152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/59
/dev/loop26                   54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop27                  256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/4
/dev/loop29                  8.5M  8.5M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/81
/dev/loop30                   54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/970
/dev/loop28                   35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop31                   90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop32                  4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop33                  3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/87
/dev/loop34                   93M   93M     0 100% /snap/openscad-nightly/1023
/dev/sda1                    236M   86M  138M  39% /boot
tmpfs                        1.5G   28K  1.5G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/herberius/.Private     103G   46G   52G  47% /home/herberius
```

Here is the message I get when I run the Software Updater, what could be wrong?

[image: Software Updater pic]

Comment: Your `/boot` shows only 39% used. Where does the "not enough space" comes from?

Comment: I get it when I run the Software Updater, I'll add the pictue.

Comment: OK, so it needs more space than what's available. The problem is the `/boot` partition is too small, one of the reasons why it isn't recommended to have that as separated partition for most of the normal usages.

Comment: So given it is on a separate partition, what options do I have? would I rather need to do new system install? or is anything there I can delete/move somewhere else?

Comment: You can try what the error message suggests and/or manage to expand that partition. Either option isn't without risks.

Comment: Well I have already done both things (run autoremove and switch Compress to xz) ...guess I'm screwed =(

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l | egrep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')
```

if apt is blocked `sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | egrep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')`

The problem by `sudo autoremove` is , it let configurations-file on system. Sometimes in `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/` so update-initramfs always build initramfs for removed Kernel.

But the /boot partition is really small.

Comment: Hi, at the end I had to do the updates in small chunks, nonetheless your instruction did cleanup some old stuff so now initramfs should looks smaller and cleaner so I'm confident the next updates will only update what is really necessary... thanks a bunch!